# Adding local directory path as hyperlinks in qgis2web

Tags: qgis2web

I'm using qgis2web, and I wonder if it is possible to add a local directory path as hyperlink in Leaflet or openlayers map popups, maybe or automatically from field's edit widget or by editing the code?

I'm trying to be able to open the local directory when I do click the hyperlink on the popups.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it should convert such links automatically, but I'm not sure. Just put the addresses in a text field. The functionality is provided by a Javascript library called Autoloader, but I can't remember which types of link it supports. You also have to watch out for the fact that some browsers can prevent links to local files (I think).